# Git checkout autocomplete suggest a branch that doesn't exists

Tags: git

Is not a big deal, but is anoying, when I switch between my current working branches, autocomplete suggest a branch that doesn't exists locally. In origin neither.

I already tried `git fetch --prune  --all` and also create a branch with that name and delete it (local and remote), but is still there in the sugestion...

Any idea? What else can I do?

Comment: What kind of autocomplete? bash? Did you try `git bash -a`?

Comment: I type `git co fran/` and pulse tab, then my current branches are sugested and one of them no longer exists

Comment: And `git bash -a` is not a git command: `git: 'bash' is not a git command. See 'git - help'. `

Comment: Yep, sorry, my mistake: `git branch -a`

Comment: Is there a directory `fran/`?

Comment: No. But `git branch -a` return something, few weeks ago we migrate from gitea to bitbucket, so, I have two origins and the ghost branch is in gitea. If you post as an answer I give you the vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `git branch -a` to see what local and remote branches your really have in the repository.

Comment: Our sysadmin department change our origin because we migrate our repos to a new bitbucket instance (from gitea). The ghost branch was on the old origin and I totally forgot

Comment: tank you but what can i do then will get suggest name by start of typeing

Comment: @ВладимирКазак What is your problem? If it's different from the question you should ask your own separate question.